# Can't access gcloud project

Tags: gcloud

I was recently added to a project managed under gcloud.
I was given full permission to all parts of the projects, yet when I try to access the VM instance of the project. It can't be loaded.

When searching it I get "Failed to load".
When trying to open the VM instances menu I get:

```
You do not have sufficient permissions to view this page

There was an error while loading /compute/instances?folder=&organizationId=&project={project name}

You are missing at least one of the following required permissions:
Project
compute.instances.list
```

The same thing happens in every other submenu.
Although, when trying to access the gcloud console of the project I get:

```
{my user name}@cloudshell:/ ({project name}) $
```

But when trying to search through the machine I can't really find anything related to the project.

Comment: I have the exact same problem.  I'm a single user, not part of an org. Created a hand full of projects yet this VM project just disappeared.   If i log into the gcloud shell, it actually tells me Ive selected the project but it is not selectable or accessible in the cgcloud console.  If i run commands to list my projects in the shell it is not listed either.  Did you resolve this?  If so please share.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you were not given sufficient permission and your account is missing one:

```
compute.instances.list
```